# Navigation bar wrap similar to visual studios in asp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a navigation bar at the top of my page with a "user" element to show the current login.

My goal is the bar to work similarly to how visual studio's does when you resize (The left navigation elements to start wrapping, while the right side login info stays fixed to the TOP RIGHT corner).

What I currently have does 99% of this. The missing 1% is the left elements wrap when they hit the right side of the window (they are ignoring the user element).

```
<div id="header_nav_buttons"> 
  <ul>
      <li><asp:HyperLink Text="Link1"/></li>
      <li><asp:HyperLink Text="Link2"/></li>
      <li class="header_session"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

#header_nav_buttons
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;

    height: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#header_nav_buttons ul
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}

#header_nav_buttons li
{
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-right: 13px;

}

.header_session
{
    float:right;
    padding-right:40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @IrishChieftain nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical RWD ([Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/)) behavior you're seeking. You need to start a new project in VS and Bootstrap should be included as part of that. You should stick to version 3 of Bootstrap as I am not sure VS has caught up with version 4 yet. You really need to tag your question better to show what version of ASP.NET you're using and what version of VS.

Right now you're using fixed units of measurement in your CSS - RWD is all percentages as everything stretches. You could use Nuget package manager to bring Bootstrap into your project, but your question is too vague for me to point you in a specific direction. Try starting with a good [tutorial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) or [two](https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-asp-net).

**UPDATE:**

When creating new styles in a project, leave the original Bootstrap.css file as is. Create a new style.css style sheet and override any of the base bootstrap styles in there, if needed; for example, you might want your buttons to look different, etc. Make sure to declare this custom style sheet AFTER the Bootstrap one in your master page. As a rule, I never customize the out-of-the-box media queries.

Comment: I did a quick test adding some of the required links and scripts to my page and I believe it is part of the project, just not being used at all. It's quite an involved project, so I can't just move it into a new project. 

A future plan was always good RWD, so I will have to look into Bootstrap and attempt to implement it. Thanks for the info, and those links have a lot of good info, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. I've had to do something like this before and it can get messy fast. If you're using master pages, start there and work inwards.

Comment: This navigation was for the master page, so I was starting there. :)
I am more concerned for the inner pages. It's a control interface system with lots of label > textbox combos, all done as individual DIV elements to allow CSS to run everything. But looking quick at Bootstrap, it appears I might need to redo all of that........ (aka messy)

Comment: Divs and even ASPNET controls are fine. Just strips out all references to CSS classes first - leave any IDs being used by CSS and style around it - these could be referenced in code-behind and you don't want to break that. You're basically stripping out all styling one page at a time. I'm going to update my answer...

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah there is quite a bit of code-behind (working on that too). This part will be the "final" piece, once I get most of the rest working.